# ntldr: could'nt open drive multi(0)rdisk(0)partition(0)

Tags: windows-xp, boot

I get this message after fresh Winxp sp3 installed, it doesn't boot windows it shows message in upper top corner of the screen. It has integrated SATA drivers and HDD is in S.M.A.R.T mode.
There are two same messages one above another.

Comment: Make sure sata controller is not set to ahci mode in bios, and bios set to legacy boot

Comment: Maininboard is Albatron KX18DS Pro, it is difficult to find actually where are options in BIOS for this ???